# Как получить информацию из JComboBox и поместить ее в JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing

Фрагмент кода из конструктора. Есть выпадающий список с такой моделью:

```
  DefaultComboBoxModel<String> position_list_model;
    position_list_model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
    position_list_model.addElement ("инженер-программист");
    position_list_model.addElement("ведущий инженер");
    position_list_model.addElement("начальник отдела");
    position_list_model.addElement("инженер-системотехник");
    position_list_model.addElement("техник");
    position_list = new JComboBox<String>(position_list_model);
    position_list.addActionListener(this);
    position_list.setPreferredSize(TEXT_FIELD_DIMENSION);
    position_panel.add(position_label);
    position_panel.add(position_list);
    add(position_panel);
```

Как мне "вытащить" из моего `JComboBox position_list` должность (текущий выбранный элемент списка) и занести эту должность в JTextArea?

У меня была мысль использовать `JComboBox.getComponent(int)`, но я не знаю какую именно должность выберут, а `this` туда передать нельзя.

Моя обработка

```
  if (e.getSource() == add_button){
        String s = new String(full_name_Text_Field.getText());
         list_of_workers.setText( s + " - " + position_list.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может быть `position_list_model.getSelectedItem();` ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в поле ничего не появляется, может я с ActionListner что то напутал? Сейчас обновлю вопрос

Comment: `position_list_model.getSelectedItem()` а не `position_list.getSelectedItem()`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ и так не работает.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/6K3r9ij.png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну не знаю )) Добавил скрин